# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in Joomla! template

Tags: jquery, joomla

I've this error in my own J template, where jquery is linked by **script** tag.

Error occurres in this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login-dropdown').click(function() { //this passes (tested with alert)
        $('.login-container').show(); // there is error
    });
});
```

for record - **.login-container** has **display:none** which could by right for **show()** method.

I suspect the conflict between jquery and joomla, but do not know how to deal with it eventually.

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla uses mootools, so there might be conflict between them.

Use [$.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.login-dropdown').click(function() { //this passes (tested with alert)
        $('.login-container').show(); // there is error
    });
});
```