# I'm getting an error with Jquery code in joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla3.0

I've a Joomla 3.6 site.  I've been trying to get a simple bit of jquery to run with no success.

```
            <script>
            if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
                console.log("not loaded");
            } else {
               console.log("loaded");
            }
            if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
                // jQuery is loaded => print the version
                console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
            }
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                console.log( "ready!" );
            });

            </script>
```

Console log shows loaded then 1.12.4 for the Jquery version and then says Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

I've now exhausted everything I can think of like adding in no conflict/unloading bootstrap/using (Jquery) after the function etc.

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.
thanks

Comment: `jQuery != $` Either you has the use it like this `jQuery(document)` or you have to initiate the [`jQuery.noConflict`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) mode.

Comment: Try jQuery( document ).ready(function() insted of $( document ).ready(function()

Comment: thanks empiric that worked perfectly.  Any idea what might cause the conflict in joomla?

Comment: See this two links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140265/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function-only-working-on-few-pages,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305941/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-in-joomla-template

Comment: @John It seems that Joomla is using MooTools which is interfering with jQuery. Here as a [doc](https://docs.joomla.org/Javascript_Frameworks) on how to include JS-Frameworks in jQuery. From this doc: `This means it is accessed via the jQuery namespace, not through $.`

Comment: So for Joomla you have to use `jQuery()` instead of your normal `$()` functions

Comment: Simple to pass `$` into ready callback though so can keep most code the same

Comment: I used it like this on my extensions `jQuery( document ).ready(function($)` so i can use $ instead of using jQuery and also it avoids conflict.